# igraph simplifies when trying to color edges

Tags: r, colors, igraph, simplify

I have several cell types and want to show their connections with each others. My problem if I just use `plot(all.cnx)`, it shows all the connections. However, if I want to add edge.color, etc. then it simplifies the graph. For instance, the connections from "CT#1_3" to other cell types. How can I prevent this simplifications, as I want to show all the edges?

thanks,
ilyas.

```
library("igraph")
my_cnxs = c("CT#1_0","CT#2_7","CT#1_2","CT#2_7","CT#1_3","CT#2_7","CT#1_5","CT#2_7","CT#1_6","CT#2_7","CT#1_0","CT#2_0","CT#1_0","CT#2_2","CT#1_0","CT#2_8","CT#1_2","CT#2_8","CT#1_3","CT#2_8","CT#1_5","CT#2_8","CT#1_6","CT#2_8","CT#1_2","CT#2_0","CT#1_2","CT#2_2","CT#1_3","CT#2_0","CT#1_3","CT#2_2","CT#1_5","CT#2_0","CT#1_5","CT#2_2","CT#1_6","CT#2_0","CT#1_6","CT#2_2","CT#1_1","CT#3_2","CT#1_1","CT#2_0","CT#1_1","CT#2_2","CT#1_2","CT#3_2","CT#1_3","CT#3_2","CT#1_5","CT#3_2","CT#1_6","CT#3_2","CT#3_2","CT#3_2","CT#3_2","CT#2_0","CT#3_2","CT#2_2","CT#2_8","CT#3_2","CT#2_8","CT#2_0","CT#2_8","CT#2_2","CT#1_1","CT#2_7","CT#1_2","CT#2_7","CT#1_3","CT#2_7","CT#1_5","CT#2_7","CT#1_6","CT#2_7","CT#3_2","CT#2_7","CT#2_8","CT#2_7")

my_edge_colors = c("green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","green","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red")

all_cell_colors = c("yellow3","red","skyblue","orange","violet","cyan3","gray80","green","darkgreen","pink","gold","cadetblue1","purple","darkkhaki","chocolate","darkred","aquamarine","darkslategray4","blue","cyan1")

names(all_cell_colors) = c("CT#4_0","CT#1_0","CT#1_1","CT#1_2","CT#1_3","CT#1_4","CT#1_5","CT#1_6","CT#1_7","CT#3_1","CT#3_2","CT#2_0","CT#2_1","CT#2_2","CT#2_3","CT#2_4","CT#2_5","CT#2_6","CT#2_7","CT#2_8")

all.cnx = graph(my_cnxs)
my_layout = layout_(all.cnx, nicely())
my.cx.names = names(edges(all.cnx)[[1]][1]) 
my_vertex_colors = all_cell_colors[match(my.cx.names, names(all_cell_colors))]
plot(all.cnx, layout = my_layout, edge.color = my_edge_colors, edge.arrow.size=0.4, vertex.color = my_vertex_colors, vertex.size=30,vertex.frame.color="black", vertex.label.color="black",vertex.label.cex=0.5, vertex.label.dist=0, edge.curved=0.2)
plot(all.cnx ,layout = my_layout)
```

Comment: By "simplfication", do you mean the merging of the edges that connects nodes CT#1_3 and  CT#2_7 ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. It merges the two edges. I want to show these edges, as they are different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edges are overlapping because of `edge.curved = 0.5`. It is making all of the edges have the same curvature, so it appears if the graph is being simplified, but really the edge are there, just overlapping perfectly.

To get back to what you wanted, less curve in edges, you can use the function `curve_multiple()` on the `igraph` object directly and pass the resulting vector to `edge.curve`.

```
plot(all.cnx, layout = my_layout,
     edge.color = my_edge_colors, edge.arrow.size=0.4,
     vertex.color = my_vertex_colors, vertex.size=30,vertex.frame.color="black",
     vertex.label.color="black",vertex.label.cex=0.5, vertex.label.dist=0,
     edge.curved = curve_multiple(all.cnx, .2)) # the default is 0.5
```

[image]

This will only curve edges where curve is needed, ie there would be overlap. If you just remove the `edge.curved` argument it resets to the default value, resulting in edges with more curvature, but no overlap.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Done!